# How to delete all active spanner sessions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have a spanner instance which currently has about 20000 active sessions connected to it. I am not sure how I would be able to delete them all in one go?

I tried makeing an api request here:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases.sessions/delete

but I can delete only one session at a time here.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an API for batch deleting sessions, and we don't currently have one planned.

The session management API you linked to is one solution. Note also that if a session is left idle for one hour, Cloud Spanner will [delete it on its own](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions#handle_deleted_sessions) (though most of the client libraries will send regular keepalive messages to sessions in their pools).